# axes change when using overlay with next3d() in rgl

Tags: r, macos, rgl

Here is a reproducible example of the problem. I want to create side by side `plot3d` in *rgl* with shared mouse.

```
#use an example from rgl's manual
set.seed(1234)
x <- sort(rnorm(100))
y <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(100) + atan2(x, y)

#create side by side plot
open3d()
mfrow3d(1, 2, sharedMouse=TRUE)
plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(100))
arrow3d(c(0, 0, 0), c(2, 2, 2), type="lines")

next3d()
plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(100))
```

All good so far.

[image: resulting side by side plot]

Now overlay the arrow3d to the plot on the right side

```
arrow3d(c(0, 0, 0), c(2, 2, 2), type="lines")
```

and the axes change with the arrow not placed correctly

[image: overlay arrow3d]

Can't figure out what is happening. If I plot each of these two plots with `arrow3d()` in separate `open3d()` calls they look identical. I tried other approaches such as `combineWidgets` in the *manipulateWidget* package, which works correctly but I can't figure out how to share the mouse across subscenes. *plotly* will be too tricky because my application require many 3d arrows along a path to create a trajectory and 3d arrows apparently are not easy to implement in *plotly* outside of annotations.

Running rgl 1.1.3 on R 4.2.2 on a mac (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0).

Comment: Confirmed using rgl 1.1.9 on R 4.2.2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Since there is no axis change with e.g. `lines3d(matrix(c(1, 0, 1, -2, -2, -2), 2), lwd=3)` I suspect a bug in the `arrow3d` function. You should file an issue at their [github](https://github.com/dmurdoch/rgl/issues), looks quite active. You can link this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the `rgl.window2user()` function that is used by `arrow3d()`.  It has been fixed in `rgl` 1.1.10, but that's only available on Github, and installing `rgl` from source isn't always easy.  Here's a bit of a hack to install just the bug fix in the CRAN version 1.1.3:

```
# This is the fixed version of rgl.window2user:

rgl.window2user <- function( x, y = NULL, z = 0, projection = rgl.projection()) {
  xyz <- xyz.coords(x,y,z,recycle=TRUE)
    
  viewport <- projection$view
    
  normalized <- rbind( 2*(xyz$x - viewport[1]/viewport[3]) - 1,
                       2*(xyz$y - viewport[2]/viewport[4]) - 1,
                       2*xyz$z - 1,
                       1 )
  asEuclidean(with(projection, t(solve(proj %*% model, normalized)))) 
}
environment(rgl.window2user) <- environment(rgl::rgl.window2user)
assignInNamespace("rgl.window2user", rgl.window2user, "rgl")
```

Code like this is not accepted by CRAN in a package, but for your own use it should be okay.  The change it makes will only last for the current R session.